# free video editing software for Linux with audio tracks auto matching

Tags: linux, audio, video

I have a few video files which basically cover the same action from different perspectives. I would like to merge them into one "split-screen" kind of video (two or four panes). The problem is videos are different lengths and align partially, for example one is 40mins long and the other one is only 5mins long somewhere in the middle, another one covers 10mins from the end of the first one and a few mins after that. I am not able to precisely match the tracks visually, I need the software that will match/align/sync the videos based on the audio tracks which contain some common "events". Is there anything available for Linux that will do the job?

Comment: Take a look at the options available in this Q&A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89142/mixing-audio-tracks-in-a-video-file-in-linux/89169#89169

Answer (score 3):

Try [Kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/)

It allows for multi-track editing, audio & video layers, and has some effects.

[image: Kdenlive]

There is also [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/), which is more complicated, and [Openshot Video Editor](http://www.openshotvideo.com/2010_03_01_archive.html).

Answer (score 0):

On LWN, there is a [Grumpy editor](https://lwn.net/Articles/84305) series, and our esteemed editor there has reviewed video editing a few times. Dated, but perhaps worth a look.